# CSS formatting image w/ text in jquery ui autocomplete widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an autocomplete widget that displays text w/ images. Currently my results look like this.

[image]

I would like to set up my results so that the words 'test' and the name 'Federico' or 'Casey' appear on different lines, right above each other.

This is the relevant part of my javascript code for the widget:

```
)
.data( "autocomplete" )
._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + "<img src='" + window.module.Globals.prototype.karma_assets + "images/_pricing_tables/best_deal.png' style='vertical-align:text-top;'/>" + item.id + " - " + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Anyone know how to format my output to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text portion of the a tag in a div element that should create the push you are looking for and allows the `<br />` to work the way you want it to. CSS3 compliant but works backwards compatible.

```
.append( "<a>" + "<img src='" + window.module.Globals.prototype.karma_assets + "images/_pricing_tables/best_deal.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; float: left;'/><div>" + item.id + " <br /> " + item.label + "</div></a>" )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.append( "<a>" + "<img src='" + window.module.Globals.prototype.karma_assets + "images/_pricing_tables/best_deal.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; float: left;'/>" + item.id + " <br /> " + item.label + "</a>" )
```

try this..

Comment: Tried that, the text appears below the image

Comment: Casey, see my edit. This is about HTML formatting, not a jQuery UI issue.